# Powershell script, how to open folder just created by script?

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to create a script for the first time in PowerShell, and I was wondering how I could `cd` into the folder the script just created?

```
Set-Location -Path G:\Backup
$folderName = (Get-Date).tostring("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss")            
New-Item -itemType Directory -Name $FolderName
```

This script will be used to do a fast backup of personal files. So I want the script to create this folder, `cd` into it and then I'll script it to copy the most important stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item) command's output to [`Set-Location`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-location):

```
Set-Location -LiteralPath (New-Item -ItemType Directory -Name $FolderName)
```

Note: The simpler and arguably more PowerShell-idiomatic formulation would be:

```
New-Item -itemType Directory -Name $FolderName | Set-Location
```

However, up to at least PowerShell 7.1.2 this has an unexpected side effect: the file-system [provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) prefix - `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::` - is then reflected in `$PWD` / `Get-Location` and therefore also in the interactive prompt string.

This problem is the subject of [GitHub issue #10522](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10522)